# Obtener el numero de columna de entre los elementos "primos"

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo la siguiente estructura html:

```
<tbody> 

<tr>
    <td><input type='text' class='celda clave' value='1'></td>
    <td>
        <select class='celda'>
            <option selected='true' disabled='disabled'>veracruz</option>
            <option>Veracruz</option>
            <option>Boca del Rio</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' class='celda' value='123'></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='celda' value='oscar'></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='celda' value='daniel'></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='celda fecha' value='2017-11-01'></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

La tabla se ve asi:

[image: tabla]

Estoy buscando que al ingresar un valor en un elemento con clase 'celda', obtener que numero de columna ha sido ingresado para entonces hacer modificaciones en la base de datos. Entonces si, por ejemplo, se ingresa un nuevo valor en la columna "Escritura" me tendria que regresar el numero 2 (tomando en cuenta que el indice comienza en 0). Si se ingresara un nuevo valor en la columna "Adquiriente" deberia regresar el numero 4.

Antes de usar tablas esto lo solucionaba con:

```
$(this).index();
```

Pero ahora como los elementos INPUT estan dentro de los elementos TD esta funcion me regresa 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas basta con seleccionar el padre directo del elemento al cual se le ha modificado el valor y aplicar la función `index()`, así:

```js
$(".celda").change(function(){
    var indice = $(this).parent().index();
    
    console.log('El índice modificado es el ' + indice)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody> 

    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' class='celda clave' value='1'></td>
        <td>
            <select class='celda'>
                <option selected='true' disabled='disabled'>veracruz</option>
                <option>Veracruz</option>
                <option>Boca del Rio</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type='text' class='celda' value='123'></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='celda' value='oscar'></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='celda' value='daniel'></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='celda fecha' value='2017-11-01'></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¡Vaya! Era mucho mas sencillo de lo que pensé, me confundi y creia que debia obtener primero el padre, luego el hermano y despues su hijo, pensaba que debia obtener lo que vendria siendo el indice de entre los primos y no me di cuenta que bastaba con el indice del padre. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, te invito a que aceptes la respuesta para que los futuros desarrolladores que tengan un problema similar sepan cual fue la solución correcta, saludos !